# ImportError in Scripts directory

Tags: python, importerror

Using windows 7 and python 2.7. I have a package named Regetron in `c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\regetron` which contains `__init__.py` and `engine.py`. When I try to run this library from the command prompt by typing `regetron` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python27\Scripts\regetron.py", line 6, in <module>
        from regetron.engine import Regetron
    File "C:\Python27\Scripts\regetron.py", line 6, in <module>
        from regetron.engine import Regetron
ImportError: No module named engine
```

I added `c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\regetron` to %PYTHONPATH% and can successfully import this module from other scripts located in other folders as well as the interactive prompt, but for some reason it refuses to run from the command prompt. What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

You actually have two problems here. Fixing either one of them would actually eliminate your immediate error, but you need to fix both of them.

> When I try to run this library from the command prompt by typing regetron

You shouldn't have a script named `regetron` and also have a module or package named `regetron`. Fix it by renaming your script. But if you want to understand why it's causing a problem:

The current working directory is always part of `sys.path`. So, you're in the directory with `regetron.py` in, and you run it with `regetron`. That means that `regetron.py` is on the path. So when you `import regetron`, it finds your script, not the package. Or, when you `from regetron import engine`, it finds your script, and tries to import a variable/function/class/whatever named `engine` from it, rather than finding the package and trying to import a module underneath it.

---

> I added c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\regetron to %PYTHONPATH%

Never add a package's directory to `sys.path`.

Since site-packages is already on your `sys.path`, the code in `regetron/engine.py` is already available as `regetron.engine`. You don't want it to *also* be available as `engine`. This will cause all kinds of problems.

---

So, rename you script to something else, remove regetron from `%PYTHONPATH%`, and everything will be fine.

But you may want to (re-)read the section on [Packages](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/modules.html#packages) in the tutorial.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. After renaming the script and removing regetron from %PYTHONPATH% I am still getting: `ImportError: cannot import name regetron`. Is this a new problem or have I failed to solve the old one?

Comment: @ubeatlenine: It sounds like you've failed to solve the old one. Two possibilities: (1) have you started a new `cmd.exe`, and verified that `%PYTHONPATH%` is empty? (2) Is there still a `regetron.pyc` or `.pyo` file lying around in your working directory? If so, you have to delete it.